# Registration with back-end fails app-engine sample code

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been working with google app engine sample ( Mobile Shopping Assistant ) https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/MobileShoppingAssistant-sample/tree/master/MobileAssistantAndroidAppEngine . I spent about a week setting up the project and fixing issues (mostly related to dependencies and configuration). Now the back-end is deployed and i can access the api through api explorer. i can execute non restricted methods and get the responses from server however when i execute admin methods i get error even when i turn OAuth on.

```
OK 401
message: Only authenticated users may invoke this operation
```

so i think that the problem is due to bad configuration

here is what i have done:

**app gradle.build**

```
apply from: 'config.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.sample.mobileassistant"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}


}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

**app build config**

```
buildConfigField "String", "ROOT_URL",
            "\"https://MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/_ah/api/\""

    buildConfigField "boolean", "SIGN_IN_REQUIRED", "true"

    buildConfigField "String", "SENDER_ID", "\"MY_SENDER_ID\""

    buildConfigField "String", "WEB_CLIENT_ID", "\"MY_WEB_CLIENT_ID\""
```

And **build.gradel** for the back-end in which i have changed the version of app engine sdk from 18 to 30

**>> note: android studio inspection reports that *appcfg* and *endpoint* symbols can't be resolved!!**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.30'
   }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7


dependencies {
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.30'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.30'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.30'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.30'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.5'
compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
}

appengine {
downloadSdk = true
appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
}
endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
}


}
```

The project id is set in **appengine_web.xml** as well as the API key. when i run the client app a reg_id is obtained but registration fails due to GoogleAuthIOException:

```
E/MainActivity: Exception=com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
```

which is thrown from **sendRegistrationIdToBackend()** method:

```
/**
 * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use
 * GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this
 * demo since the device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes
 * back the message using the 'from' address in the message.
 */
private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
    try {
        shoppingAssistantAPI.registrations()
                .registerDevice(regId).execute();
        // Persist the registration ID - no need to register again.
        storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.warning("Exception when sending registration ID to the "
                + "backend = "+ e.getMessage());
        // If there is an error, we will try again to register the
        // device with GCM the next time the MainActivity starts.
    }
}
```

now this method calls

```
shoppingAssistantAPI.registrations()
                .registerDevice(regId).execute();
```

however in the back-end source code there is different class name and method signature ... class **Registration.class** with setters and getters & **RegistrationEndpoint** withe **registerDevice(String regId,UserAccount user)**

**And that is what i am confused about?? 
can somebody explain to me what the problem with this code ,, and how i can get the client app communicate with the back-end correctly.**

**---UPDATE---**

the client app requests a method (chickIn method) which requires an argument that is not yet available (regId)  this kind of weird!!

```
03-01 20:07:48.898 25083-25359/com.google.sample.mobileassistant W/MainActivity: Exception when checking in =com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
03-01 20:07:51.581 25083-25359/com.google.sample.mobileassistant W/MainActivity: Exception when sending registration ID to the backend = null
03-01 20:07:51.601 25083-25083/com.google.sample.mobileassistant I/MainActivity: Device registered, registration ID= APA91bF2eC6o9_KBI2coPMqqXE94lECzeYLnrD30nmK2PvmoHg3pFfVuxYkLir3HPV07gq-n-UZZOsM1EUSQOfR8WnWYaG1iDFbx0IuIOLNKIMdeDimPAH5H7DURDqZZ8hWdrsStnS4sEHHTB155bx91L7FpV0txHA
03-01 20:07:52.292 25083-25359/com.google.sample.mobileassistant E/MainActivity: Exception=com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
```

Comment: I recall you had to set the user you are using to log into the admin area to owner in the developer console.

Comment: hi  @dmaij...  where should i add the user ?... in the config file ?? can explain more

Comment: No, in the google developer console, there should be a project owner that should be used to login to the admin part. You should not be able to login to the admin part with your device actually.

Comment: you mean credentials .. yes i obtained credentials as per the documentation of the sample app. one an api key  and 2 client id's

Comment: That's not what I meant. Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService

Comment: thanks @dmaij .. the app contains a UserAccount Entity which implements com.google.appengine.api.users.User .. you may have a look at the source code at github and suggest what i need to edit.

Comment: I don't see where you provide auth credentials in the client. See [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#making_authenticated_calls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for accessing non restricted api methods from the android app ... it might be helpful for others whom are suffering because of OAuth ...

I added **server:client_id:** to the server client id and it worked :)

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

> **In Your Android App**
>
> You’ll need to call the Google Play services
> GoogleAuthUtil class to get an ID token; the procedure is as described
> in Obtaining an Access Token. There’s one extra bit of magic: the
> value of the scope argument to the getToken(email, scope) method. It
> has to be the string audience:server:client_id:X, where X is the
> Client ID of for the Web app, as described above. If our Client ID
> were the example value given above, the value of the scope argument
> would be
> audience:server:client_id:9414861317621.apps.googleusercontent.com.